# CentOS Operating Systems do not update packages

Tags: google-compute-engine

Friends,

I have some packages from the CentOS distribution that need to be updated, such as:

expat-2.1.0-11.el7
libpng-1.5.13-7.el7_2

For versions:

expat-2.1.0-12.el7
libpng-1.5.13-8.el7

However, newer packages are not found in the repositories.

I have already cleared the cache and updated using the command yum clean all and yum check-update, even so the problem continues.

Would this be a problem with the Google Compute Engine (GCE) or would it be a problem related to the distribution itself?

Edit :

Output command yum clean all:

> yum clean all Loaded plugins: fastestmirror Cleaning repos: base epel
> extras google-cloud-compute google-cloud-monitoring google-cloud-sdk
> kernelcare nginx-mainline
> : nginx-stable remi-php72 remi-safe salt-latest updates zabbix zabbix-non-supported Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors Other
> repos take up 14 M of disk space (use --verbose for details)
>
> Output command yum check-update: yum check-update Loaded plugins:
> fastestmirror Determining fastest mirrors epel/x86_64/metalink
> |  14 kB  00:00:00       * base: linux.cc.lehigh.edu  * epel:
> d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net  * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net  *
> remi-php72: remi.xpg.com.br  * remi-safe: remi.xpg.com.br  * updates:
> repos-va.psychz.net base
> | 3.6 kB  00:00:00      epel
> | 4.7 kB  00:00:00      extras
> | 2.9 kB  00:00:00      google-cloud-compute/signature
> |  454 B  00:00:00      google-cloud-compute/signature
> | 1.4 kB  00:00:00 !!!  google-cloud-monitoring/x86_64/signature
> |  454 B  00:00:00      google-cloud-monitoring/x86_64/signature
> | 1.4 kB  00:00:00 !!!  google-cloud-sdk/signature
> |  454 B  00:00:00      google-cloud-sdk/signature
> | 1.4 kB  00:00:00 !!!  kernelcare
> | 2.6 kB  00:00:00      nginx-mainline
> | 2.9 kB  00:00:00      nginx-stable
> | 2.9 kB  00:00:00      remi-php72
> | 3.0 kB  00:00:00      remi-safe
> | 3.0 kB  00:00:00      salt-latest
> | 2.9 kB  00:00:00      updates
> | 2.9 kB  00:00:00      zabbix
> | 2.9 kB  00:00:00

Output /etc/yum.repos.d/

> CentOS-Base.repo CentOS-Vault.repo kernelcare.repo remi-modular.repo
> remi-php74.repo CentOS-CR.repo CentOS-x86_64-kernel.repo nginx.repo
> remi-php54.repo remi-php80.repo CentOS-Debuginfo.repo epel.repo
> remi-glpi91.repo remi-php70.repo remi.repo CentOS-fasttrack.repo
> epel-testing.repo remi-glpi92.repo remi-php71.repo remi-safe.repo
> CentOS-Media.repo google-cloud-monitoring.repo remi-glpi93.repo
> remi-php72.repo salt-latest.repo CentOS-Sources.repo google-cloud.repo
> remi-glpi94.repo remi-php73.repo zabbix.repo

Comment: Can you post the output of the commands you are running, as well as the contents of your repository files in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`?

Comment: Output command yum clean all:

yum clean all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Cleaning repos: base epel extras google-cloud-compute google-cloud-monitoring google-cloud-sdk kernelcare nginx-mainline
              : nginx-stable remi-php72 remi-safe salt-latest updates zabbix zabbix-non-supported
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
Other repos take up 14 M of disk space (use --verbose for details)

Comment: Add the output of `yum repolist` to your question. Edit your question and add it. Don't post it in the comments.